# Another dateTime question

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, solr

I currently have a date in this format

```
2010-03-03 10:39:18
```

which is a `TIMESTAMP` field in MySQL. I need to have the date in this format for a search engine called Solr:

```
1995-12-31T23:59:59Z
```

Here is some text from their website about dates:

> Solr expects dates to be in UTC when
>   indexing. The format for this date
>   field is of the form
>   1995-12-31T23:59:59Z, and is a more
>   restricted form of the canonical
>   representation of dateTime
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime.
>   The trailing "Z" designates UTC time
>   and is mandatory. Optional fractional
>   seconds are allowed:
>   1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z All other
>   components are mandatory.

I was given this code from another Q here on SO, but it doesn't work. Solr complains about an "invalid time string":

```
$solr_date = date('c', (strtotime($date_from_mysql)); // doesn't work
```

When echoing `$solr_date,` the trailing `Z` mentioned above isn't there. Thanks.

Comment: You looking for a java solution or php?

Comment: @Bhushan: PHP, from what the code sample looks like.

Comment: @pesar: have you tried using one of the PHP libraries for interacting with Solr? http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/ http://pecl.php.net/package/solr http://code.google.com/p/solphr/

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just convert it to UTC?

```
    $datetime = "2010-01-19 00:00:00";
    echo "Datetime Before: ".$datetime."<br />";
    $dttostr = strtotime("2010-01-19 00:00:00");
    echo "Datetime After: ".formatToUTC($dttostr)."<br />";
    echo "System Timezone: ".date_default_timezone_get()."<br />";

    function formatToUTC($passeddt) {
        // Get the default timezone
        $default_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

        // Set timezone to UTC
        date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

        // convert datetime into UTC
        $utc_format = date("Y-m-d\TG:i:s\Z", $passeddt);

        // Might not need to set back to the default but did just in case
        date_default_timezone_set($default_tz);

        return $utc_format;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ! this helped me a lot. I spent so many hours searching for a solution !

Comment: According to the ISO 8601 spec, you need to have leading zeros on all of the fields. You have them on all with the exception of the hours field. The 'G' should be an 'H' ->  Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's worth noting that date/time columns in MySQL are not stored in any specific string format. They are converted into strings when printing them and you can choose how to format them.

If you want a pure MySQL solution, the functions that are relevant to your problem include [CONVERT_TZ()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) to obtain the UTC time and [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to display it as required. E.g.:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '+01:00', '+00:00'),
    DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '+01:00', '+00:00'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ')
```

The problem is basically that you have to know your timezone beforehand since TIMESTAMP columns do not allow to store such information. Also, you may find issues with daylight saving time.

About PHP, the [date()](http://www.php.net/date) function allows to combine format code, you're not limited to only one:

```
<?php
$ts = strtotime($date_from_mysql);
$solr_date date('Y-m-d', $ts) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', $ts) . 'Z';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

just use

`gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $time);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of a hack but it works for me:

```
$to = date('c', strtotime($to)).'.000Z';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another alternative:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2010-01-19 00:00:00');
echo str_replace('+00:00', 'Z', $datetime->format('c'));
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zr5i3k)

Answer (score -1):

Here it is PHP solution  :

Split  your  ( 2010-03-03 10:39:18 )  date string based on the mktime function arguments.

`$solr_date = date('c', mktime($year,$month,$date, $h, $m , $s)); # it will work`

Comment: The signature for `mktime()` is `mktime(hour, minute, second, month, day, year)`...

Comment: It very likely *won't* work. `date('c', …)` formats a local date with trailing timezone as `+00:00`, and Solr expects UTC time with a trailing `Z`.