# Solr not saving time in UTC format

Tags: solr

If I had defined a field of type Solr.DateField, I read SOLR always saves it in GMT. But I see that SOLR just takes the time that is in defined in my DB and writes it without conversion.

Is there any configuration parameter for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Solr stores dates *exactly* as you feed it, disregarding any timezone information. It's up to you to convert from/to UTC. [Here's a forum thread that confirms this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/having-problem-about-Solr-Date-Field-td1630911.html).

For example, [here are some conversion routines for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370171/another-datetime-question).

Comment: I have a machine where solr does this conversion automatically but it is not happening when the same code is run on another machine where  machine itself is set to GMT. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SOLR-1-4-1-Indexing-DateField-time-zone-problem-td1966118.html explains some of it.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer i'm not sure, if i understand you right. Does it mean, that solr interprets all the dates as UTC. So it's up to the developer to feed solr with UTC dates only? This means: i have to convert dates before sending to solr and `2012-12-13T14:42:16.437Z+01:00` (with `+01:00`) does not work?! Do you know, if there is any change in Solr 4?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know the ONLY dateformat SOLR will accept is:

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000Z (The Z is important!)

Comment: "Z" is from "Zulu Time" or "Zero Time", which is GMT=0 (or UTC=0)

Comment: Thanks, by chance to you know why? In the documentation they say they accept date in ISO format, but i didn't found a reference in which we should force the represention to GMT (ending with Z)

Answer (score 1):

in my case, our server is set to non UTC time. when solr retrieves a row from the database, it automatically converts that time to UTC.

the problem is the data that is stored in DB *is* already in UTC. but because when solr pulls that data, it does another conversion to UTC....

the right way for our purposes (in my opinion) is to have the server set to UTC timezone... but alas, that would mess the entire server farm up... i don't do ops, and i do not know the ramifications. in any case, I'm trying to find a way to resolve this in my code.

Answer (score 1):

As Mauricio Scheffer states, SOLR doesn't care about timezones, which is frustrating.

BUT!  If you have a non-UTC time *and* you know the timezone when you index the value, you can convert it to UTC on the fly in your SOLR update:

"2013-02-07T11:21:51Z+8HOUR"

This looks a bit weird, but adding "Z+8HOUR" to a PST timestamp will convert it to the correct value in UTC.   In general, you can use any [DateMath](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_1/org/apache/solr/util/DateMathParser.html) modifier when indexing a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that the date I am giving to SOLR does not have timezone set in it and in such a case it defaults to whatever timezone the machine is set to.