# Solr Date Format issue in the  Query

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am trying to implement the solr query using .NET but i am getting bad request when i try to connect to the solr for search since my date format is wrong.Can any one tell me the exact syntax to create a date format in .net

Created_Dt :[12/12/2008 3:45 PM TO *]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get the solr date format using the code below,

```
DateTimeFieldSerializer date = new DateTimeFieldSerializer();

string fromDt = date.SerializeDate(searchCriteria.From);

string toDt = date.SerializeDate(searchCriteria.To);
```

This works fine and I can search using the date range now..

Comment: but what about date format? you mean to say we have to store date in string format right....???

Answer (score 5):

SolrNet already does the conversion to Solr time format for you, you only need to work with the standard `DateTime` type:

```
new SolrQueryByRange<DateTime?>("Created_Dt", new DateTime(2008, 12, 12, 15, 45, 0), null);
```

Comment: i am not able to query date in this manner ,can you please let me know any alternate way since i am not using the solrQueryByRange option

Comment: @Selwyn: the example in your question is a range query. Are you not using SolrNet? Do you not need a range query? Why can't you query date in this manner? Please be more specific.

Comment: I am constructing the query string  manually by appending it to string builder so i exactly have no idea where i need to insert the above code line.and also binding the date in it .

Comment: @Selwyn: why? you tagged SolrNet, are you not using SolrNet?

Comment: I am using solr net actually i am implementing it for the first time ..so would like to know if there is any way of constructing queries by using solr net methods itself.

Comment: @Selwyn: take a look at SolrNet http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/ it takes care of many things for you when using Solr in .net applications.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search based on a [UTC timestmap](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html). Here is some example .NET code to generate it:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"));
```

And a query using your example field that would use that format:

```
Created_Dt:[2011-06-07T13:35:47Z TO NOW]
```

Also, make sure you convert your dates to [UTC format before you store them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149606/solr-not-saving-time-in-utc-format).