# DateTime Solr Converter in MVC

Tags: datetime, model-view-controller, format, solrnet

I have this problem, I am using Solr in my MVC website. And I have filed DateTime for search. And If you whant to search with datetime condition, you have to write in this datetime input filed this format:

yyyy-dd-mmThh:min:secZ  => so it have to be: Year-Day-Mounth T Hour:Minute:Second Z ; letters T and Z have to be between. Without this format, solr query is not working.

In my Controller I have this:

```
public ISolrQuery BuildQuery(SearchParameters parameters
...
if (parameters.Date.HasValue && parameters.Date2.HasValue)
{
   solrQueries.Add(new SolrQueryByRange<DateTime>("date", parameters.Date.Value.Date, parameters.Date2.Value));
}
```

In my Model I have this:

```
[SolrField("date")]
public ICollection<DateTime> Date { get; set; }
```

In my Binder I have this:

```
DateTime date1;
  if (DateTime.TryParse(qs["date"], out date1))
     sp.Date = date1;
DateTime date2;
  if (DateTime.TryParse(qs["date"], out date2))
     sp.Date2 = date2;
return sp;
```

And in my SearchParameters I have:

```
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
public DateTime? Date2 { get; set; }
```

I have no idea how to convert in correct format to execute search query in solr. Realy thanks for any idea.

Comment: This is already handled by SolrNet for you - see previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265247/solr-date-format-issue-in-the-query

Comment: It is true, it handle it self, I haven't been puting correct value in field. Thanks.